# Machine can access network and Internet but can't be accessed by others

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp

We have a Windows XP SP3 machine on our network which is able to access the network (local shares and computers and also external websites on the Internet) but is inaccessible to other machines on the local network. We need to access it on the LAN.

We have tried what is suggested here on [this thread](http://forums.techguy.org/networking/953976-solved-cant-ping-computers-network.html), to no avail.

Machine is added as a workstation in Active Directory and was successfully added to domain. It even gets the default wallpaper from the server. We've tried pinging it using its IP address but did not succeed.

It sees the network but the network can't see it.

Comment: maybe obvious question: is the Windows Firewall properly configured? If it's enabled with default configuration, it is expected that you can't ping and/or connect to the machine using SMB/CIFS.

Answer (score 3):

Do a `sc stop sharedaccess` from Start / Run and see if the behavior changes. If it does, then Windows Firewall is the culprit.

Comment: I've found out Windows Firewall is STOPPED in services and can't be STARTED.

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting when you attempt to start the service?

Comment: exactly what is stated here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920074/en-us, except this is an SP3 machine.

Comment: When I run your command, @evan, I get [SC] ControlService FAILED 1062: the service has not been started.